# What is the most efficient way to replace an element in an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have been slowly working on a library that would allow a user to dynamically build an array in the C language.  Of the many functions I have written, I have developed a solution to replace the value at a user defined index with another value, but I am not sure it is a very efficient solution and would like any thoughts if someone might have a better method that does nto require creating several intermediate arrays to store data.

I am using a `typedef struct` titled `Array` which acts as a container for the pointer variable `array`, as well as `len` that contains the active length of the array, `size` which contains the allocated size of the array, `elem` which contains the memory allocation per indice, which can change depending on the data type chosen by the user, `name` which is a character string the user can assign to each array instantiation, and `dat_type` which references an `enum` to describe the data type the array was instantiated with.

So far I have built several functions to work in conjunction with the `Array` container, of which the most relevant for this question are the following functions;

**type_dat**
An enum with variables for `float`, `double`, `char`, and `int`.

**Array** a `struct` that acts as a container for an array.

**array_mem_alloc**
The function allocates memory for the array and should not be called directly.

**init_array**
This function acts as a wrapper around `array_mem_alloc` and is how the user should instantiate an array.  This returns an `Array` container.

**append_array** This allows a user to append a scalar or an array to the array within the `Array` container.

**preappend_array** This function allows a user to ad a scalar or an array to the beginning of an array within the `Array` container.

**int_array_val** This function retrieves integer variables from the array.  There is a version of this function for each data type; however, this specific function is relevant to the example below.

**replace_int_array_indice** This function allows a user to enter a specific indices and replace the variable at that indice with another integer value.  I have coded a solution for this function, but I do not believe it is an efficient implementation.  In the below example, the implementation requires that two intermediate arrays be created to store data before the `memmove` and `memcpy` function can bring all of the data together.  **I am hoping that someone can tell me if there is a better solution for this function then the one I am providing below**.

My files are shown below

array.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum
{
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE,
    CHAR,
    INT
} dat_type;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
    void *array;  // Pointer to array
    size_t len;   // Active length of array
    size_t size;  // Number of allocated indizes
    int elem;     // Memory consumption per indice
    char name[20];   // The array name
    dat_type dat;
} Array;
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void array_mem_alloc(Array *array, size_t num_indices);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Array init_array(dat_type dat, size_t num_indices, char *name);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int append_array(Array *array, void *elements, size_t count);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int int_array_val(Array *array, int indice);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int preappend_array(Array *array, void *elements, size_t count);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void replace_int_array_indice(Array *array, int index, int replacement_value);
#endif /* ARRAY_H */
```

Array.c

```
void array_mem_alloc(Array *array, size_t num_indices) {
    // Determine the total memory allocation and assign to pointer
    void *pointer;
    pointer = malloc(num_indices * array->elem);

    // If memory is full fail gracefully
    if (pointer == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
        free(pointer);
        exit(0);
    }
    // Allocate resources and instantiate Array
    else {
        array->array = pointer;
        array->len = 0;
        array->size = num_indices;
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Array init_array(dat_type dat, size_t num_indices, char *name) {
    // Determine memory blocks based on data type
    int size;
    switch(dat) {
        case FLOAT:
            size = sizeof(float);
            break;
        case INT:
            size = sizeof(int);
            break;
        case DOUBLE:
            size = sizeof(double);
            break;
        case CHAR:
            size = sizeof(char);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Data type not correctly entered, instantiating int array!\n");
            size = sizeof(int);
            dat = INT;
    }

    // Allocate indice size and call array_mem_alloc
    Array array;
    array.dat = dat;
    array.elem = size;
    array_mem_alloc(&array, num_indices);
    strcpy(array.name, name);
    return array;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int append_array(Array *array, void *elements, size_t count) {
    // Allocae more memory if necessary
    if (array->len + count > array->size) {
        size_t size = (array->len + count) * 2;
        void *pointer = realloc(array->array, size * array->elem);
        // If memory is full return operations
        if (pointer == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        // Allocate memory to variables and increment array size
        array->array = pointer;
        array->size = size;
    }
    // Append variables and increment the array length
    memcpy((char *)array->array + array->len * array->elem, elements, count * array->elem);
    array->len += count;
    return 1;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int preappend_array(Array *array, void *elements, size_t count) {
    // Allocae more memory if necessary
    if (array->len + count > array->size) {
        size_t size = (array->len + count) * 2;
        void *pointer = realloc(array->array, size * array->elem);
        // If memory is full return operations
        if (pointer == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to allocate memory, exiting.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        // Allocate memory to variables and increment array size
        array->array = pointer;
        array->size = size;
    }
    // Preappend variables and increment the array length
    memmove(
    ((char *) array->array) + count * array->elem,
    array->array,
    array->len * array->elem);

    memcpy(array->array, elements, count * array->elem);
    array->len += count;
    return 1;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void replace_int_array_indice(Array *array, int index, int replacement_value) {

    // THIS FUNCTION WORKS, BUT I DO NOT THINK IT IS AN EFFICIENT IMPLEMENTATION
    // Copy data to intermediate array
    int arr[array->len];
    memcpy(arr, array->array, array->elem * array->len);
    memmove(((char *) array->array), arr + index + 1, array->len * array->elem);
    array->len -= index + 1;

    // preappend with replacement value
    preappend_array(array, &replacement_value, 1);

    // preappend with initial indices up to replaced index
    int new_arr[index - 1];
    memcpy(new_arr, arr, index * array-> elem);
    preappend_array(array, &new_arr, index);
}
```

main.c

```
#include "array.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argc[]) {
    size_t indices = 10;
    char name[6] = "array";
    dat_type dtype = INT;
    Array arr_test = init_array(dtype, indices, name);
    int a[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    append_array(&arr_test, a, 6);
    replace_int_array_indice(&arr_test, 1, 5);
    for (int j = 0; j < array_test.len; j++) {
        printf("%d\n", int_array_val(&arr_test, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's far too much text in this post. Problem descriptions should be clear and concise, and we shouldn't have to read a book to try to understand the issue. Please [edit] your post to provide a short, clear problem description and ask a specific question. You may want to review [ask] for some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are definitely overthinking this one.

You only need to replace one value in the array, so find the offset, cast correctly, dereference and assign:

```
* (int *) ((char *) array->array + index * array->elem) = replacement_value;
```

Or, continue to work with `memcpy` when building base functionality, and use that to create further abstractions.

```
void array_set(Array *array, size_t index, void *data) {
    memcpy(
        (char *) array->array + index * array->elem,
        data,
        array->elem);
}

void int_array_set(Array *array, size_t index, int value)
{
    array_set(array, index, &value);
}
```

Might want to check that `index` is valid.

Comment: Yes, I did overthink this problem!!!

Comment: One question.  For the purpose of error handling, should I just provide a warning of the index is not valid, or should I change the function to return an appropriate int value of the inputs are not correctly entered?

Comment: You have a few options. For a function like this, you could simply return a boolean value, as it only has one failure state. For more complex functions, you could combine this with setting [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error) (or just return error codes as `int` or `errno_t` (C11), wherein `0` is success), or roll your own set of error codes to return, e.g., `typedef enum { A_OK, A_INVALID, ... } ArrayStatus;`. I would avoid printing warnings (`stderr`), unless you want to provide a way to optionally enable such behaviour (on a library / thread / object based level).

Comment: Remember, if you are writing a library, you are preparing code for other developers to use. They might have their own preferred solutions to common problems (e.g., logging, aborting, etc.). Usually it is enough to just indicate *why* the library code failed, and let them handle it from there. If rolling your own codes, you may wish to implement an auxiliary functions that mimics [`strerror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror).

Answer (score 0):

btw, you have a memory corruption vulnerability in your code. in `init_array` you are using `strcpy(array.name, array);`, when name is only 20 bytes long. and `name` is user controled. you should use `strncpy(array.name, array, sizeof(array.name);` instead.